# Show that $Tx = y - \alpha f(x) x$ is a contraction

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-point-iteration, banach-fixed-point, contraction-operator

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ a bounded linear functional, $y \in X$ fixed and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that if $|\alpha| < C$, then the non-linear equation $x + \alpha f(x) x = y$ has a unique solution $x$ in the ball $B = \left\{x \in X : ||x - y|| \leq 1\right\}$.

Let $Tx = x + \alpha f(x) x$. My strategy is to show that $T$ is a contraction; that is, $||Tx - Tz|| < ||x - z||$ for $x, z \in X$. Then I could apply the Banach fixed-point theorem to reach the conclusion.

Unfortunately I am having trouble showing that $T$ is a contraction. I get as far as showing $||Tx - Tz|| = ||(x - z) + \alpha (f(x)x - f(z)z)||$. I've tried the adding zero trick by adding then subtracting $\alpha f(x) z$ but this yields nothing that will show that $T$ is a contraction.

This is where I would like help.

Comment: I don't think it is a contraction.

Comment: Yeah, whenever $\alpha f(x)>0$, it fails to be a contraction.

Comment: I could see no manifest method to show it's a contraction.

Comment: Should it read $B = \{x \in X : \|x - y\| \le C\}$? Otherwise, I do not see any influence of $C$.

Comment: @gerw The problem is as written. Error would originate from the question sheet I was given (this is to help study for a qualifying exam).

Comment: Then, this is odd. Similarly, w.l.o.g. you could take $\alpha = 1$ by replacing $f$ by $\alpha \, f$.

Comment: So to those claiming that $T$ is not a contraction, can you think of another way to solve the problem?

Comment: Note that the fixed points of $T$ are not solutions to your equations. Further, every $x$ in the kernel of $f$ is a fixed point of $T$. Hence, $T$ cannot be a contraction if the dimension of $X$ is at least $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $T$ as you have defined it has a fixed point $x$, then
$$x=x+\alpha f(x)x,$$
or $\alpha f(x)x=0,$ which doesn't give us the equation you're looking for.  What you should try to show is that the map $T$ given by
$$Tx=y-\alpha f(x)x$$
is a contraction on $B$.  Now we calculate:
\begin{align*}
\|Tx-Tz\|&=|\alpha|\|f(x)x-f(z)z\|\\
&\leq|\alpha|\left(\|f(x)x-f(x)z\|+\|f(x)z-f(z)z\|\right)\\
&\leq|\alpha|\|f\|\left(\|x\|+\|z\|\right)\|x-z\|
\end{align*}
Now, since $B$ is bounded, there is some $M>0$ such that $\|x\|,\|z\|\leq M$.  This gives us 
$$\|Tx-Tz\|\leq2M|\alpha|\|f\|\|x-z\|,$$
So if we let $C=\frac{1}{2M\|f\|}$, if $|\alpha|<C$ then $T$ is a contraction on $B$ and the result is true.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not true as written.

Take $X = \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha = 1$, $f(x) = \frac12 \, x$ and $C = 2$. Then, your equation reads
$$x + \frac12 x^2 = y$$
with solutions
$$x = -1 \pm \sqrt{2 \, y + 1}.$$
If $y$ is chosen correctly, none of these solutions lies in the ball $B$.

Comment: but is f defined as in your solution a bounded linear functional? Am sorry it's just a doubt

Comment: Of course. $f$ is linear and has norm $1/2$.